# MySQL send error in bash because of space

Tags: mysql, linux, database, bash, centos

I am trying few commands in Linux terminal (centos)

```
mysql -u whoisdat_count -pMYPASSWORD -D whoisdat_count -e "CREATE TABLE COUE (`T 001` varchar(255));"
```

it prompts me an error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255))' at line 1
```

But when I run same command in PHPmyAdmin

```
CREATE TABLE COUE (`T 001` varchar(255));
```

it work perfect

My Syntax for database connect is fine because that work>>

```
mysql -u whoisdat_count -pPASSWORD -D whoisdat_count -e "INSERT INTO COUE values ('pp p');"
```

What Should I do so it read space in `T 001`?

Answer (score 2):

On shell, when enclosed in double-quotes, backticks are interpreted part of a command.

Either escape backticks

```
mysql -u whoisdat_count -pMYPASSWORD -D whoisdat_count -e "CREATE TABLE COUE (\`T 001\` varchar(255));"
```

or enclose your query on single quotes

```
mysql -u whoisdat_count -pMYPASSWORD -D whoisdat_count -e 'CREATE TABLE COUE (`T 001` varchar(255));'
```